# search does not work when localReader is used to bind the grid data

Tags: search, jqgrid

I am using localReader to set the totalRecords, totalPages and CurrentPage for the data coming in from server. But because of this, my search is not working.

Can somebody explain me how search works in jqgrid? Does it require anything for postData? do i need to set postData explicitly somewhere?

If i am not using localReader, the search works fine.

Thank you in advance.

Regards,
Jay

Comment: It has worked for me now. I implemented the server side search which is working perfect for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has worked for me now. I implemented the server side search which is working perfect for me.